# Creating Objects in Python using a Dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I was working on a python code that allowed a user to create categories, then fill in these with as many objects they wanted. Last, I printed everything and created a text document with the info using File I/O.

Because the user can enter as many categories and airplanes, I couldn't control the number of parameters in the **init** for the class. I wanted to create a dictionary that created properties for the Airplane object that were the keys of the dictionary, and values for these properties that were the values. How would I do this?

Thanks.

```
    class Airplane:
        def __init__(self, dictionaryPerhaps):
            #How could I make properties that were the keys and had properties that were the values?
            pass

    def objectCreation(valuesOC, catagoriesOC):
        thePlanes = { }
        for each in catagoriesOC:
             thePlanes [each] = valuesOC[each]

        theAirplaneObject = Airplane(thePlanes)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and output?

Comment: you can subclass dict, and you only have to worry about implementing the specific functionality of your class

Answer (score 2):

> How could I make properties that were the keys and had properties that were the values?

```
def __init__(self, dictonaryPerhaps):
    self.__dict__.update(dictionaryPerhaps)
```

If you'd rather pass everything as keyword argumrnets to `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(**kwargs)
```